# Modules : AttributeError (Python)

Tags: python, function, module

I have a module called message (were I wrote down functions) and another module which is my main (where I make function calls). When I run my main I get the following message :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCoSi.png

Here is the screenshot of my "message" module :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFYmb.png

Please help me make this code run.

I tried to change the code but nothing worked.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! Be sure to read up on [the question asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get better answers faster. I believe your issue is caused by incorrect syntax in `message.py`. There should be no space between the function name and the colon, e.g. `def goodbye() :` should be `def goodbye():`

Comment: Make sure your files are saved, it should work since it seems your terminal is also on the "Code" folder containing both files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As said above, make sure the `message` file is saved. In the images, it reflects that it is not saved.